# C++ class method that can be called using virtual dispatch or like a static function with no object context

Tags: c++

I have some example code shown below that calls a class member function from a static context without first creating a proper instance of the object to call on.

I know this code seems strange and I don't want to go into a whole lot of side tracks discussing the reasoning behind where it came from unless it becomes relevant to answering the question.

**My questions are:**

1. Is the code below "correctly formed" according to the C++ spec?
2. If it is not correctly formed, then in what circumstances could I
   expect this code to not work as expected (see sample output for an
   example of expected outcome)?

I believe the following are some limitations with this:

- Referencing "members" from a virtual base may cause undefined behavior
- Actually making use of the "members" when called statically may cause
  undefined behavior

The key thing to look at with regards to this question is the function: StaticCall(). Note that when calling using StaticCall(), I expect that none of the members will actually be used. It is primarily to enumerate type information about the available members without implementing a nearly duplicate second function.

Sample code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Serializer;

template <typename ClassT> void StaticCall(Serializer& s)
{
    // First create aligned storage for a "fake" this pointer for the member function call
    //
    // This allows us to de-reference obj and access addresses of members so long as we
    // don't actually try and use the members as they are pointing to uninitialized memory
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(ClassT), __alignof(ClassT)>::type data;
    ClassT* fake_obj = static_cast<ClassT*>(static_cast<void*>(&data));
    fake_obj->ClassT::Serialize(s);
}

template <typename ClassT> void VirtualCall(ClassT& obj, Serializer& s)
{
    obj.Serialize(s);
}

template <typename ClassT> void MemberCall(ClassT& obj, Serializer& s)
{
    obj.ClassT::Serialize(s);
}

class Serializer
{
public:
    enum Mode
    {
        MODE_STRUCTURE
        , MODE_CONTENT
    } mode;

    template <typename TypeT> void DisplayStructure()
    {
        mode = MODE_STRUCTURE;
        StaticCall<TypeT>(*this);
    }

    template <typename TypeT> void DisplayContentVirtual(TypeT& obj)
    {
        mode = MODE_CONTENT;
        VirtualCall(obj, *this);
    }

    template <typename ThisT> void Type(ThisT* obj, const char* obj_name)
    {
        std::cerr << "Type: " << obj_name << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename ParentT, typename ThisT> void TypeWithBase(ThisT* obj, const char* obj_name)
    {
        std::cerr << "Parent ";
        if (mode == MODE_STRUCTURE)
            StaticCall<ParentT>(*this);

        else if (mode == MODE_CONTENT)
            MemberCall(static_cast<ParentT&>(*obj), *this);

        std::cerr << "Type: " << obj_name << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename MemberT> void Member(MemberT& member, const char* member_name)
    {
        std::cerr << "Member: " << member_name;
        if (mode == MODE_CONTENT)
            std::cerr << " : " << member;

        std::cerr << std::endl;
    }
};

// Example usage
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(int i) : pmem_int(i), pmem_str("Hello") {}
    virtual void Serialize(Serializer& s)
    {
        s.Type(this, "Parent");
        s.Member(pmem_int, "pmem_int");
        s.Member(pmem_str, "pmem_str");
    }

    virtual void Thing() = 0;

    int pmem_int;
    std::string pmem_str;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    float cmem_float;
    Child() : Parent(1234), cmem_float(334.0f) {}

    virtual void Thing() {}

    virtual void Serialize(Serializer& s)
    {
        s.TypeWithBase<Parent>(this, "Child");
        s.Member(cmem_float, "cmem_float");
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Serializer s;
    std::cerr << "Parent structure: " << std::endl;
    s.DisplayStructure<Parent>();

    std::cerr << "\nChild structure: " << std::endl;
    s.DisplayStructure<Child>();

    Child c;
    Parent* p = &c;
    std::cerr << "\nContent: " << std::endl;
    s.DisplayContentVirtual(*p);

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output produced:

```
Parent structure:
Type: Parent
Member: pmem_int
Member: pmem_str

Child structure:
Parent Type: Parent
Member: pmem_int
Member: pmem_str
Type: Child
Member: cmem_float

Content:
Parent Type: Parent
Member: pmem_int : 1234
Member: pmem_str : Hello
Type: Child
Member: cmem_float : 334
```

Comment: maybe a silly question, but why don't just just create a temp instance of ClassT named fake_obj on the stack within StaticCall?

Comment: You cant always create an instance of ClasT, in the example calling it for ParentT, ParentT is an abstract class so I cant create an instance of it. Likewise it may not have a default constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `StaticCall` has undefined behavior (§9.3.1 [class.mfct.non-static]/p2):

> If a non-static member function of a class `X` is called for an object
>   that is not of type `X`, or of a type derived from `X`, the behavior
>   is undefined.

`data` is pure storage; it's neither an object of type `ClassT` nor an object of a type derived from `ClassT`. It doesn't matter whether your non-static member function actually uses a member of that class. You are in UB land as soon as you make the call.

Comment: Are you saying that `data` is an area of memory that is not initialized or constructed?

Comment: @RichardChambers: Yes, that's exactly what `aligned_storage` gives you: "The member `typedef type` shall be a POD type suitable for use as **uninitialized** storage for any object whose size is at most `Len` and whose alignment is a divisor of `Align`."

Comment: I guess it is back to the drawing board. This solution was the only elegant one so far from a usage perspective. My understanding is as soon as you enter UB land, then even if it works in most cases (tried this on windows, mac, linux, iOS and android in release builds) things like the optimizer may be permitted to just remove the call entirely and be well within their right.

Comment: @user1265365 How about putting the bulk of `Serialize` inside a static member (with an extra pointer parameter) and then have the non-static virtual `Serialize` simply dispatch to it? (`Serializer::Member` may need to take a pointer-to-member so that no dereferencing occurs for the null case.) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/134c6f8f58155f17

Comment: Yes. That is how I started to implement this (using pointer-to-member variables) and likely what I will end up doing. The markup of serializable types is just not as nice as what could come out of the above proposal.